# How should I portray experience in two unrelated fields on LinkedIn or my resume?

Tags: resume, work-experience

I worked as a Front end web developer for 2.5 years and later I worked as an Office manager for 2.5 years. Both jobs gave me very good experience and knowledge.

Now I want to look for new opportunities and I am unable to update LinkedIn / my resume profile due to separate fields.

Should I include both fields or just single field on LinkedIn or my resume?

I am afraid that because of unrelated fields I might not get calls and I want to apply in both fields.

Comment: I edited your question and changed "update" to "include". If you meant something else, feel free to [edit] it appropriately.

Comment: Personally for me, I tailor my resume for the job and keep my LinkedIn profile all-inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Early in your career, you definitely want to include both, because 50% more professional experience is going to count for a lot, even if it were in an unrelated field.

If it were your last job, you also want to include it, since the obvious question would be "what have you been doing for the last X years?" and that could get your resume thrown out.

If you've worked many jobs, you can arguably leave a few of them that were long ago off, since you're trying to highlight your past experiences to best sell yourself, not give a complete work history.

---

Of course you can choose how much detail you want to go into for any given role on your resume, depending on how the skills you used there and your achievements relate to any new jobs you're applying for.

This is again very dependent on how much experience you have - if you don't have much to say, including a decent achievement that's unrelated to your target job is likely to only count in your favour, while doing so when you have a lot of other information on your resume might distract from more important things.

Answer (score 2):

Include both for three reasons:

- You want to apply for both positions
- You have worked for the same time in each of them
- You believe that each position gave you valuable experience

Answer (score 2):

Recently I watched the talk [Weird Game Dev: Unusual Roles and How to Get Them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3LyiCdHI14), and I got some solid career advice out of it.

The focus of the talk is how unusual career paths can get you into the game industry, but you can apply it to any industry.

The key takeaway is this: even if your career path seems odd from the outside, it usually **tells a story**. Try to find which story your career tells and make it a strength.

The example that he gives about himself is brilliant. He was a boxing coach and a community manager for a videogame website. What story you get out of it? He portrays himself as a mentor, with passion to teach others.

So my advice is that if you can find a compelling story that ties both of this positions together you can turn it into an advantage.